# DebuggerStepThrough in python?

Tags: c#, python, debugging, pycharm

Is there a way to mark a certain method in python so that the debugger won't step into it while debugging ?
(I'm using PyCharm, so if there's something specific that the IDE can help me with, that would be great too)

For those familiar with C# - I'm looking for a DebuggerStepThrough attribute in python...

Answer (score 2):

For PyCharm: Go to `Preferences` > `Build` > `Execution` > `Deployment` > `Stepping` > `Python`

Configure "Do net step into scripts" with glob patterns of the scripts you do not want to step into.

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm has a "Step Over" button right next to the step into button. Step over goes into the next line in the file rather than to the next line that will be executed. The keyboard shortcut for step over is <kbd>F8</kbd>.

Comment: Yes, familiar with that, but not really what I'm looking for.. I want a way to mark a method that will always be 'stepped over', even if I choose 'step into' in the debugger. This is very convenient for large projects when you don't want to keep accidentally 'stepping into' trivial code (i.e.: logging methods) or methods that lead to 3rd party libraries you're not interested in digging into.